# Having an issue with the default response Content-Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, content-type, httpmodule

I have a website that has the following Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>...</htm>
```

I discovered an issue causing certain mobile browsers to break (blackberries and older androids). On the Android for instance, when a request is made it sends this header:

```
Accept: application/xml,appliation/xhtml+xml,text/html ...
```

The problem is that my site doesn't conform to XHTML but IIS decides that since the browser requesting the page prefers xhtml then it should serve that instead of `text/html`.

I've tried overriding it by adding `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to the page, but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to tell iis to stop serving xhtml for all requests to `http://mydomain.com/mobile`. I was thinking of doing it by overwriting the Response.Content-Type in an HttpModule.

Is there anything I'm missing here? What's the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't have the funcionality you mention (to overide the content-type of output from .NET) as it's up to the application to do this.  What happens on the mobiles when they 'break', can you provide a HTTP debug trace?

To test to see if the ContentType really is the problem, add this to the Page_Load event of one of your pages, then view that page on the affected mobile.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Mobile browsers have quirks to desktop versions, they parse JavaScript, handle DOM elements differently.  Mobile Safari for example has an imcomplete Date.parse() method, which causes the JS to break on that page.

Try running the mobile browser in debug mode (if possible) and see what the actual error is.  As I can't see how IIS would change the content type willy nilly, especially to a XHTML type which means the underlying HTML has to be **perfect**,

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your DOCTYPE to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and see if that helps. Also, have a look at the following reference:

[W3C Recommended list of Doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)